# How to test the Index?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, testing, ninject

In MVC4,I inject the Controller by using the Ninject and I want to test the "Index".
Injection of the writing(The controller for injection):

```
public class NinjectDependencyResolver : IDependencyResolver
{ 
    private IKernel kernel;

    public NinjectDependencyResolver()
    {
        kernel = new StandardKernel();
        AddBindings();
    }

    private void AddBindings()
    { 
        kernel.Bind<IDB>().To<DB>();
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.TryGet(serviceType);
    }

    public IEnumerable<object> GetServices(Type serviceType)
    {
        return kernel.GetAll(serviceType);
    } 
}
```

The IDB:

```
public interface IDB
{
    IBugTrackRepository iBugTrackRepository { get; }
    ICategoryRepository iCategoryRepository { get; } 
    ...
    ...
    IUserRepository iUserRepository { get; }
}
```

To achieve:

```
public class DB : IDB
{    
    public IBugTrackRepository iBugTrackRepository
    {
        get { return new BugTrackRepository(); }
    }
    public ICategoryRepository iCategoryRepository
    {
        get { return new CategoryRepository(); }
    }
    ...
    ...
    public IUserRepository iUserRepository
    {
        get { return new UserRepository(); }
    }
}
```

To achieve:

```
public class BugTrackRepository : IBugTrackRepository
{
    private DBEntities context = new DBEntities ();

    public IQueryable<BugTrack> bugtrack
    {
        get { return context.BugTrack; }
    }
    ...
    //Other database operations...
}
```

The Controller:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{     
    private IDB repository; 
    public HomeController(IDB repo)
    {
        repository = repo;
    }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        ViewBag.mytitle = "Home Page";
        return View();
    }
}
```

The Test Code:

```
    [TestMethod]
    public void TestIndex()
    {
        HomeController controller = new HomeController(??);

        ViewResult result = controller.Index() as ViewResult;

        Assert.AreEqual("Home Page", result.ViewBag.mytitle);
    }
```

but this test is wrong and  I don't konw how to instantiate this Controller.Please help me!Have any questions please leave a message.

Comment: Use Ninject.MVC3, Dont mess about with your own Dependency Resolver implementations, life is too short. Dont use `i` prefixes on variable names, they make eyes bleed!

Answer (score 1):

Your Home's constructor contains IDB interface, so you need to pass it there.

As you have interface you can use mock objects (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37359/what-c-sharp-mocking-framework-to-use) to imitate your IDB.